# Django: How to set up a test server with fixtures but Django models containing ForeignKeys?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm trying to directly test my client code (with `requests` module) to call my Django API.
However, I want to automate this.

What I'm trying to do is create a model with test server running.
How am I able to populate my testdb with fixtures if one of my models has a ForeignKey?

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Load(models.Model):
    load_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    invoice_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    >customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    carrier = models.ForeignKey(Carrier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Edit: I linked the doc pertaining to this question. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/

Per the docs it has the following:

```
 [
  # I added the myapp.Band as an example of my issue
  {
    "model": "myapp.Band",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "band_name": "The Beatles"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Paul",
      "last_name": "McCartney"
    # "band": ??? how would I assign?
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Is there something preventing you from creating the fixture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking at `Natural Keys`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys

Answer (score 1):

If you have the fixture created, update your database settings and run the [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#loaddata) command to load the fixture to the database.

Comment: I linked the doc here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/ . For example, say the model `Person` has a ForeignKey of `model.Band`. In the `fields`, would I just add myapp.Band?

Comment: Yes, you need to create all the data in the fixture that you want in the database.  So if your model requires a ForeignKey related model you'll need to create the related model first.

Comment: I just updated my question with a scenario (line contains the `???`). So I would just create the fixture of `Band`, but the docs doesn't show how to assign the band to the FK field in `person`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just the PK of the related FK.

Answer (score 0):

Fixtures are often over-rated compared to using [Factoryboy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to generate test objects, including large batches of them for testing list-views and Django-filter views. I found [this article](https://hacksoft.blog/improve-your-tests-django-fakes-and-factories/) extremely helpful in explaining how to combine them. The pain with fixtures comes when you add or remove fields from your models and forget to regenerate your fixtures. Or worse, if you  leak information that really shouldn't have been made publicly accessible.

One warning - don't test factories from the `manage.py shell`. They automatically save the objects they generate! Instead write a test to test the factories. To avoid this mistake I put all my factories in one pseudo-app called `fakery` and in the `__init.py__` file above the factory codes,

```
import sys
if len( sys.argv) >= 2 and sys.argv[1].find('shell') >= 0:
    print("\nWARNING -- don't forget that Factories will save all objects they create!\n")
```

so if you import any of them into a shell, you see a warning.

Comment: I actually like Factoryboy for testing directly with my server. But how would I be able to use FB with the testserver command as I want to test my client while server running?

Comment: @dearprudence You could write a view which checks that you are running with a test DB, checks that the test models have not yet been created, and then invokes the same test-object creation routines that your tests use.